# How to write JPA specification for postgres text[] array

Tags: spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-criteria

```
 @Column(columnDefinition = "text[]")
 @org.hibernate.annotations.Type(value = CustomStringSetType.class)
 private Set<String> touchedBy;
```

How to write a JPA specification for this `touchedBy`?

In database I have

```
"{idcn8,idcn6,idcn7,idcn4,idcn5}"
"{idcn2,idcn1}"
"{idc1,idc2}"
"{idc4}"
```

I want to pass values like `idcn1`, `idcn5` to the JPA specification and filter the rows. Could anyone help me how to achieve this?`

I am not sure how to write specifications to filter array values. Could someone help me with how to write?